# WordPress Admin Dashboard Hanging after Upgrading PHP / MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache, php-7.1

So, long story short, the latest version of Apache was causing some errors with my particular setup so I did a quick on-the-fly upgrade to PHP 7.1.6, swapped to mpm-event, and started using PHP-FPM. I guess it probably reinstalled MySQL somewhere in there too.

The front end of my WordPress site seemed relatively fine after the upgrade. The admin dashboard is okay sometimes -- but every so often trying to post a new page, or do something similar it will hang indefinitely. If I restart Apache it snaps back to attention, but nothing short of restarting the service seems to do the trick.

During this time, the frontend of my site will also start hanging until I restart Apache.

Obviously, there's something wrong with my configuration somewhere, but I'm having a really tough time pinpointing what it is. The front-end of my site is super quick until I do something on the back-end that decides to stall it all out.

I've been checking every error log I can think of, but I don't see anything happening in the apache2 error log when this happens. As far as I can tell I enabled PHP-fpm error logging but I don't see anything showing up there either.

How can I figure out what's going wrong at this point?

Any help would really be appreciated. I've spent at least fifteen hours trying to figure this out already with zero progress.

Thanks, guys.

---

```
php -v
PHP 7.1.6-1~ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Jun  9 2017 08:26:34) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.1.6-1~ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies

apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.26 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2017-06-30T08:42:23
```

/var/log/apache2/error.log -- not reporting any errors.

/var/log/fpm-php.www.log -- empty.

/var/log/mysql.err -- empty.

/var/log/mysql.log -- empty.

```
/var/log/php7.1-fpm.log

[04-Jul-2017 02:08:40] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 741
[04-Jul-2017 02:08:40] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[04-Jul-2017 02:08:40] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
```

PHP modules --

```
php -m
[PHP Modules]
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
igbinary
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
memcached
msgpack
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
readline
redis
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tidy
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

a2query -m:

```
a2query -m
dir (enabled by maintainer script)
headers (enabled by site administrator)
env (enabled by maintainer script)
authz_host (enabled by maintainer script)
reqtimeout (enabled by maintainer script)
include (enabled by site administrator)
rewrite (enabled by site administrator)
auth_basic (enabled by maintainer script)
alias (enabled by maintainer script)
authz_core (enabled by maintainer script)
asis (enabled by site administrator)
status (enabled by maintainer script)
cache (enabled by site administrator)
echo (enabled by site administrator)
autoindex (enabled by maintainer script)
authz_user (enabled by maintainer script)
fastcgi (enabled by maintainer script)
actions (enabled by site administrator)
filter (enabled by maintainer script)
mime (enabled by maintainer script)
expires (enabled by site administrator)
setenvif (enabled by maintainer script)
mpm_event (enabled by site administrator)
socache_shmcb (enabled by site administrator)
authn_file (enabled by maintainer script)
proxy (enabled by site administrator)
access_compat (enabled by maintainer script)
ssl (enabled by site administrator)
deflate (enabled by maintainer script)
authn_core (enabled by maintainer script)
suexec (enabled by site administrator)
negotiation (enabled by maintainer script)
proxy_fcgi (enabled by site administrator)
speling (enabled by site administrator)
http2 (enabled by maintainer script)
info (enabled by site administrator)
proxy_http2 (enabled by site administrator)
```

I'm not sure what it is, but /var/log/apport.log contains a few errors like this:

```
ERROR: apport (pid 12399) Tue Jul  4 00:26:27 2017: called for pid 12251, signal 11, core limit 0
ERROR: apport (pid 12399) Tue Jul  4 00:26:27 2017: executable: /usr/sbin/apache2 (command line "/usr/sbin/apache2 -k start")
ERROR: apport (pid 12399) Tue Jul  4 00:26:27 2017: is_closing_session(): no DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS in environment
ERROR: apport (pid 12399) Tue Jul  4 00:26:27 2017: apport: report /var/crash/_usr_sbin_apache2.0.crash already exists and unseen, doing nothing to avoid disk usage DoS
```

/var/log/kern.log:

```
Jul  4 02:08:39 localhost kernel: [    2.667815] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
Jul  4 02:08:39 localhost kernel: [    2.691111] Request for unknown module key 'Magrathea: Glacier signing key: d120c47c14beb62ead6703d41712cc110575d297' err -11
Jul  4 02:08:39 localhost kernel: [    2.716583] Request for unknown module key 'Magrathea: Glacier signing key: d120c47c14beb62ead6703d41712cc110575d297' err -11
Jul  4 02:08:39 localhost kernel: [    2.717334] Request for unknown module key 'Magrathea: Glacier signing key: d120c47c14beb62ead6703d41712cc110575d297' err -11
Jul  4 02:08:40 localhost kernel: [    5.345061] audit: type=1400 audit(1499148520.484:8): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/874/status" pid=874 comm="mysqld" requeste$
Jul  4 02:08:40 localhost kernel: [    5.345262] audit: type=1400 audit(1499148520.484:9): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=874 comm="mysqld"$
Jul  4 02:08:40 localhost kernel: [    5.345373] audit: type=1400 audit(1499148520.484:10): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/874/status" pid=874 comm="mysqld" request$
Jul  4 02:08:40 localhost kernel: [    5.391287] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
Jul  4 02:08:40 localhost kernel: [    5.577297] Request for unknown module key 'Magrathea: Glacier signing key: d120c47c14beb62ead6703d41712cc110575d297' err -11
Jul  4 02:10:10 localhost kernel: [   95.097387] perf interrupt took too long (2626 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50000
Jul  4 02:26:07 localhost kernel: [ 1052.647086] audit: type=1400 audit(1499149567.761:11): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/1445/status" pid=1445 comm="mysqld" reque$
Jul  4 02:26:07 localhost kernel: [ 1052.647352] audit: type=1400 audit(1499149567.761:12): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=1445 comm="mysql$
Jul  4 02:26:07 localhost kernel: [ 1052.647513] audit: type=1400 audit(1499149567.761:13): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/1445/status" pid=1445 comm="mysqld" reque$
Jul  4 02:26:23 localhost kernel: [ 1067.895962] audit: type=1400 audit(1499149583.008:14): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/1446/status" pid=1446 comm="mysqld" reque$
Jul  4 02:26:23 localhost kernel: [ 1067.896241] audit: type=1400 audit(1499149583.012:15): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=1446 comm="mysql$
Jul  4 02:26:23 localhost kernel: [ 1067.896340] audit: type=1400 audit(1499149583.012:16): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/1446/status" pid=1446 comm="mysqld" reque$
Jul  4 02:31:19 localhost kernel: [ 1364.640301] perf interrupt took too long (5248 > 5000), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 25000
Jul  4 02:37:26 localhost kernel: [ 1731.575398] audit: type=1400 audit(1499150246.686:17): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/1540/status" pid=1540 comm="mysqld" reque$
Jul  4 02:37:26 localhost kernel: [ 1731.575508] audit: type=1400 audit(1499150246.686:18): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/sys/devices/system/node/" pid=1540 comm="mysql$
Jul  4 02:37:26 localhost kernel: [ 1731.575596] audit: type=1400 audit(1499150246.686:19): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/1540/status" pid=1540 comm="mysqld" reque$
Jul  4 02:42:49 localhost kernel: [ 2054.276362] perf interrupt took too long (10122 > 10000), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 12500
Jul  4 04:00:02 localhost kernel: [ 6687.106794] perf interrupt took too long (20184 > 20000), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 6250
```

Will get more information edited in shortly.

Comment: So what were those errors initially? Or did you simply start an update/upgrade orgy unconditionally?

Comment: Apache 2.4.26 causes segfaults when used in conjunction with several modules I needed such as http2. I saw someone else reporting that their setup with PHP 7.1.6, PHP-FPM, and Event MPM was unaffected by this so I made a snap decision to follow that upgrade path. -- and I should mention that those segfaults, at least, have not been reappearing since I upgraded. They'd been in the apache2 error log previously. So whatever is happening now is something different.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So the next step is to check the logging, right? Looks like you have to add the relevant parts of your configuration to the question, since we cannot guess those.

Comment: What you describe might also indicate some general effect of the underlying system: low number of free inodes or similar. It might be worth to monitor the system log file as well.

Comment: The apache error log itself isn't turning up anything whatsoever when this stalling happens. -- Can you give me a bit more direction about what specific info / files / configurations I should post here? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, you already mentioned that. What about the other log locations? PHP, syslog, ...? And did you enable rewrite logging, since wordpress is well known to mess around with that a lot?

Comment: That is not a log file...

Comment: Is there a better way I can post log excerpts?

Comment: Sorry, please stop adding content in comments. There is an `edit` link below your question. All such valuable information belongs into the question.

Comment: All right, I've added a bunch of misc. stuff that I've scraped together to the main post. I'm not sure about syslog, since it seems to extensive...

Comment: Ok, great, thanks. Hm, `php -v` reports about the CLI version that is installed, that has _nothing_ to do with the apache or fastcgi versions present on your system. But I doubt this is an issue with the php installation. Looks more like some deadlock thing to me.

Comment: What does the system do when you experience such a "hang"? What about CPU load, Memory load? And what does the development console in your browser show for those requests?

Comment: When it's hanging the CPU and memory don't seem to change really, according to the top command. I've got 2GB total memory and usage stays around 15-25% both when hanging and otherwise. I'm not completely sure how to read the cpu usage in top, but watching it during a "hang", it shows 99.5 - 100 % cpus as "id" (idle?). So I don't really think I'm running out of resources.

Comment: As far as dev console... all http requests show as "pending" under the chrome Network tab. In the console itself, it shows nothing until the connection finally times out, then says: "GET https://www.example.com/wp-admin/load-styles.php?c=0&dir=ltr&load%5B%5D=dashicons,admin-bar,common,forms,admin-menu,dashboard,list-tables,edit,revisions,media,themes,about,nav-menus,widgets,site-icon,&load%5B%5D=l10n,buttons,wp-auth-check&ver=4.8 net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED"

Comment: 100% CPU means 100% load on the CPU. So full load. That is not good. What processes cause that load?

Comment: How long _exactly_ does it take until the connection is closed?

Comment: Reason why I ask about that time: is that a client side timeout or is the server process terminating? I wonder if it is blocked or in a busy state. If that is a busy state, then maybe this simply is a question of the maximum execution time? Try changing it, does the time you have to wait until that "timeout" change then?

Comment: There aren't any processes that show up using more than like 0.3% of CPU though. When I looked it up it said that the (id) column was idle, as in not being used? Nearly every process is showing as 0.0% and a couple are at 0.2% or 0.3%.

Comment: I don't have a stopwatch but I'll try to get a more precise time. It's odd because when it's not hanging everything is lickity-split quick. I can click back and forth between two links in the dashboard and it will load each one immediately, back and forth, over and over -- and then just randomly on the sixth or seventh click (same link I just loaded immediately) it will hang until it times out.

Comment: That points towards a deadlock. What about the FPM configuration? Not enough processes?

Comment: I'm pretty ignorant about FPM. I've left my configuration at the default, however. Looking at the file it looks like it defaults to process.max = 0, which is unlimited.

Comment: Also, Chrome reported that the "hang" timed out after exactly 5 minutes. I have "ProxySet connectiontimeout=5 timeout=240" in my vhost config file.

Comment: Also points towards an issue with apache not getting a connection to the FPM server.

Comment: How would I go about diagnosing/troubleshooting that?

Comment: Never did that myself. You will need to dig into the FPM configuration. First thing: logging. Next thing: manual usage.

Comment: So I just disabled PHP-FPM entirely, re-enabled module PHP7.1 with mpm_prefork and it's still doing the same thing. I'm going to revert back to FPM, but what else could it be at this point?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request).

Comment: Not being able to edit out server information seems like sort of a hostile policy. Anyways, I still haven't figured this out, but it seems to not have the issue when I disable mod_http2. So I guess it still has to do with that, but the segfault errors I was getting pre-upgrade aren't showing up in any logs now so I'm sort of at a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed today that my server was reporting an available update for Apache. I am slightly confused because 'apache2 -v' showed 2.4.27 both before and after this update. But whatever it was fixed my problem.

Related to CVE-2017-9789, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "wp-config.php" and set "WP_DEBUG" to true just like in the following example:

`define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );`

Now refresh the frontend and the backend page in order to be able to see the PHP errors.

You can also go to the admin area, Settings, Permalinks and click once again on the "save" button. This will override the .htaccess file.

You can install a log service, search on google for logly or sentry. Those might help also.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to see a couple unrelated code issues this way which I cleaned up, but it doesn't seem to be anything affecting my issue above. I'm pretty sure this is related to my server config somehow.

Comment: Try these tutorials: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts and https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-the-apache-web-server-on-an-ubuntu-or-debian-vps. In case that they don't help, please provide the apache config (virtual hosts) for your website.